# Error: Unable to initialise options more than once

Tags: polkadot-js, api, cryptography, keyring, ui

I am using polkadotjs/ui-keyring in which i am trying to use different accounts stores based on user preferences. And i am calling the loadAll to get all the accounts to the keyring, as shown in the example here.

```js
   keyring.loadAll({ss58Format: 88, store: myStore})
   keyring.accounts.subject.subscribe((accounts) => {
            console.log("accounts", accounts)
    })
```

Suppose i want to change the accountStore at some time later to `myStore2` if i call the same code above with the `loadAll` function, I am getting an error

```
uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to initialize options more than once
    at KeyringOption.init (index.js:34:19)
```

Is it not possible to revert the loadAll and reinitalize the ui-keyring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/ui/blob/0837376d008d6b90e548a41a91acf426703ebd34/packages/ui-keyring/src/types.ts#L29C1-L36C2) the `KeyringOptions` which contain the `KeyringStore`. Those options are what's called by [`loadAll()`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/ui/blob/0837376d008d6b90e548a41a91acf426703ebd34/packages/ui-keyring/src/Keyring.ts#L295) in line 326: `this.KeyringOptions.init(this)`. If we then go to see what that [`init`](https://github.com/polkadot-js/ui/blob/0837376d008d6b90e548a41a91acf426703ebd34/packages/ui-keyring/src/options/index.ts#L50) does, we can see that sets `hasCalledInitOptions` to `true`, that is why it throws that error.

So the issue is that you can't use `loadAll()` twice, because between the things that it does it initializes the Keyring, and you can't initialize the keyring twice.

There's currently no way to reset the `KeyStore` and replace it with another one, I guess in order to prevent a running process to go look for a key that's no longer there. There's also no way to replace the current store once it's set, what you can do is add or remove keys to it, but not in the scope of the store itself.

The way to proceed is to teardown the UI and restart it with the new keystore or run a `forEach()` to empty the store and another one to add the new keys.